# Which of the following is NOT a root class in the context of Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Which of the following is **NOT a root class** in the context of Objective-C?

a. `NSObject`

b. `NSNetworkService`

c. `NSBase`

d. `NSProxy`

(its a single select question)

I get this question in a online exam for iOS 6. I know`NSObject` and `NSProxy` are root classes. But I am not aware of any class with name `NSNetworkService` or `NSBase`.

I am wondering what is the correct answer for this question.

Note: *I have cleared that test and not posting this question for cheating.*

Comment: uh oh. This seems like a terribly detailed question. Why should anybody need to know that?

Comment: @Sulthan - To clear the same exam?

Comment: The funny thing is - there is no problem to declare my own root classes and I can name it `NSBase`. why not?

Comment: Are you sure it was NSNetworkService not NSNetService?

Comment: I am very much sure that its "NSNetworkService"  (I have screenshot of that question, because it confused me most)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of the classes `NSNetworkService` and `NSBase` (of course someone could name his class with prefix `NS`). `NSObject` and `NSProxy` are base classes, though. So the correct answer is `b` and `c`.

**Edit** (thanks Abizern): In the context of iOS, only `NSObject` is available which would add answer `d` to the set of classes NOT being a root class. I guess the opposite question "Which of the following classes *are* root classes?" would have been easier to answer given the fact that you said you can choose only one option ;)

Comment: +1 NSObject and NSProxy http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html

Comment: so you mean the answer is  b & c ?

Comment: But I can select only one!

Comment: No need to flip a coin. There is only one answer in an iOS environment.

Comment: @abizern the question asks which class is *not* a root, which means b and c are equally valid. The apple doc linked by Oleg implies NSProxy is still technically *defined* on iOS, just never used in the API.

Comment: Not in the context of the question - which is iOS. NSProxy is not used in Cocoa-Touch. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html

Comment: @abizern I think you misunderstood the point of my comment. The question asks which is ***NOT*** a root class.

Comment: Considering that only one of them is a root class, I don't see how you can ask which one is not. Either the OP has the question wrong (possible, it wouldn't be the first time) or the actual test put in a bogus question (very likely).

Answer (score 0):

see in the following link

1) `NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies; it has no superclass.

2) Cocoa supplies two root classes: `NSObject` and `NSProxy`. Cocoa defines the latter class, an abstract superclass, for objects that act as stand-ins for other objects; thus `NSProxy` is essential in the distributed objects architecture. Because of this specialized role, `NSProxy` appears infrequently in Cocoa programs. When Cocoa developers refer to a root or base class, they almost always mean `NSObject`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW35

**Edit**

see this link http://samplecodebank.blogspot.in/2013/06/NSNetService-getInputStream-example.html

but there is no any discription of `NSBase` on Google or SO

So the answer is `c. NSBase`

Comment: Its a single select question and there is no NSBase also